# How can I require a user to change their password?

Tags: password, administrator

I created a new account on a machine and gave it a default password but I want to ensure the user changes the password when they log into it for the first time. It's just a laptop with nothing special running client version of Mac OS X 10.6.8.

I'm sure it's possible, I remember seeing a check box where you could require the user to change their password at some point.

Could someone refresh my memory on this or tell me how to achieve this goal?

Comment: You're going to be more specific, what's your setup? Mac OS Server, ...? There's not a lot people can don't with the information you just gave us.

Answer (score 2):

Found on [Apple Support Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/message/8845888#8845888).

Go to

- Workgroup Manager
- Select the User or Users
- Advanced Tab
- Options

Comment: I'm not on a Mac right now, so I can't test or post screenshot. Also, there's a solution with "Server Admin" on the link I posted, but I think this on is only when it's a "network account".

Comment: this looks like it will only work with server

Comment: @mcgrailm, it will work without server as long as you target it to server "localhost".

Answer (score 2):

1. Download and install [Server Admin Tools 10.6](http://support.apple.com/downloads/Server_Admin_Tools_10_6) or [10.7.2](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1457) from Apple.
2. Run Workgroup Manager with `localhost` as a server address and admin credentials.
3. Choose desired user, then Advanced tab, Options... button, tick Password must: be changed at next login.
4. Press Save, Disconnect.